# PHP $selected_radio with two NAMES

Tags: php, radio-button

I need to create a PHP script that will check against the values of radio buttons in two separate groups. How do I add more than one radio button group? Can the names be separated with the pipe character? i.e.

```
<?PHP

$selected_radio = $_POST['food|drink'];
print $selected_radio;

?>
```

Comment: Use different `$_POST` key then, e.g. `$_POST['food']` and `$_POST['drink']`. (also, use lowercase php opening tag)

Comment: What do you mean with separate groups? Please post your HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is superglobal associative array, the elements inside it are mapped to their own keys.

In your case, `food` and `drink` are the keys themselves

So the way you combine 2 values into a single variable is by concatenating them:

```
$selected_radio = $_POST['food'].$_POST['drink'];
```

Or in your case you want to separate the values with `|` , then :

```
$selected_radio = $_POST['food']."|".$_POST['drink'];
```

You can't do `$_POST['food|drink']`;